# How to convert negative exponent without bias in Single Precision Floating Point

Tags: floating-point

I'd like to convert -0.6875(decimal) to SinglePrecision Floating Point Number without Bias.
I know how to convert it with Bias 127.
But this is the first time to hear change it without Bias.
-0.6875(decimal) is -0.1011 (binary) and make it scientific
it is -1.011 * 2^-1
Now I have to express the exponent -1 without Bias.
How to do this?
My textbook says it is impossible to use complement 2 in Floating Point Number.

Comment: There is no mathematical reason the exponent field in a non-standard floating-point format could not be two’s complement. To store an exponent of −1, simply decide what encoding you want to use for the exponent field, and store −1 in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how `-0.6875` is represented in regular IEEE-754 SP format:

```
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------S23----------
   Binary layout: 1 01111110 01100000000000000000000
      Hex layout: BF30 0000
       Precision: Single
            Sign: Negative
        Exponent: -1 (Stored: 126, Bias: 127)
  Classification: FP_NORMAL
          Binary: -0b1.011p-1
           Octal: -0o5.4p-3
         Decimal: -0.6875
             Hex: -0xBp-4
```

So the exponent is `-1`; and your instructor wants it stored as a 2's complement number? No worries, in 2's complement `-1` in 8-bits is: `11111111`. So, you can represent it as:

```
1 11111111 01100000000000000000000
```

Note that in this "system" you'll have to figure out how your format represents infinities and NaN. In regular IEEE-754 an exponent of all `1`s is reserved for this purpose, so you'll have to "decide" how to represent them in your system (or decide if you simply will not represent such numbers), since `-1` will be confused with the choice IEEE754 makes.

As Eric Postpischill indicated in his comment, there's really no right-or-wrong way to decide how to lay out your bits. There are of course good and bad ways to do so, and IEEE754 makes these choices for good reasons. (Biased exponents make comparisons easier.)

Your message says "My textbook says it is impossible to use complement 2 in Floating Point Number." Strictly speaking, this is not true. But perhaps they're alluding to the fact that it's not possible to do so while also keeping the same notion of infinity/NaN values as IEEE-754 does. If you can provide the context in which your textbook makes this claim or provide a reference otherwise, you might get a better answer.